# Subquery many-to-many relation in Django 1.9

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I have such models:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    min_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    max_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = GenreManager()

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'id'


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, related_name='genres')
    suggested_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = BookManager()
```

and I want to query it in such way: there can be duplicates (when min/max age changes, new object will be saved to db), but I want to get the latest one, so I come up with:

```
class GenreManager(models.Manager):
    def get_latest_genre_obj(self, genre):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(name=genre).latest()
```

to be able to retrieve one. Now, I want to get books, using `Genre` object from above - I need min and max age values in my query. I've tried something like this:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_books_from_genre(self, genre):
        genre = Genre.objects.get_latest_genre_obj(genre)
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(actual_genre=genre).filter(actual_genre__min_age__gte=F('suggested_age'), actual_genre__max_age__lte=F('suggested_age'))
```

But it looks like I cannot annotate object to other object:

```
AttributeError: 'Genre' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'
```

So, how to query it like I want to? I thought about `Subquery()` as I thought it can help me, but it's Django 1.11 feature andI'm using 1.9 version. To sum up what I want to achieve: from genres, retrieve newest (with highest `id`) object with particular name and use it's fields while querying for books - so I need to have access to it's fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `annotate` from the code, and use it like this:

If you want Books for a specific genre:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_books_from_genre(self, genre):
        genre_object = Genre.objects.get_latest_genre_obj(genre)
        return self.get_queryset().filter(genres=genre_object)
```

Now if you want to have books from multiple genre with same name, then you can try like this:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_books_from_genre(self, genre):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(genres__name=genre, genres__min_age__gte=F('suggested_age'), genres__max_age__lte=F('suggested_age'))
```